# Difference between * and & when passing a string to any function?

Tags: c++

This is a simple operator overloading program I learned and I can't understand exactly why the parameterized constructor is using '*st' and not just 'st' or '&st'.

Now, I know the difference between passing by reference, address and value.
In the given example, I passed a string. If it was passing by reference, the argument in the parameterized constructor would have been '&st'. I'm not sure if it is passing the string by address.

Basically, I don't know how the code is working there. Please explain that and also why using '&st' in place of '*st' isn't working.

```
class tyst
{
    int l;
    char *p;
public:
    tyst(){l=0;p=0;}
    tyst(char *st)
    {
        l=strlen(st);
        p = new char[l];
        strcpy(p,st);
    }
    void lay();
    tyst operator + (tyst b);
};

void tyst::lay()
{
        cout<<p<<endl;
}
tyst tyst::operator+(tyst b)
{
    tyst temp;
    temp.l=l+b.l;
    temp.p = new char[temp.l];
    strcpy(temp.p,p);
    strcat(temp.p,b.p);
    return temp;
}
int main()
{
    tyst s1("Markus Pear");
    tyst s2("son Notch");
    tyst s3;
    s3=s1+s2;
    s3.lay();
    return 0;
}
```

So, I'd really appreciate if anyone can clear this up for me.

Comment: i think this [Linke](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`st` is a C-style string. Passed by value

```
tyst(char st)
```

you would merely get a single character.

Passed by reference

```
tyst(char & st)
```

You would also get only a single character, but you could modify it. Not so useful in this case. You could also pass in a reference to a pointer, but I don't see much use to that, either.

How this is working

```
tyst(char * st)
```

says that the function will take a pointer, and that pointer may be pointing to a single character, the first of an unknown number of characters, absolutely nothing, or complete garbage. The last two possibilities are why use of references is preferred over pointers, but you can't use a reference for this. You could however use a `std::string`. In C++, this would often be the  preferred approach.

Inside `tyst`, the assumption that an unknown, but null-terminated, number of characters is pointed at, and this is almost what is being provided. Technically, what you are doing here with

```
tyst s1("Markus Pear");
```

is illegal. `"Markus Pear"` is a string literal. It may be stored in non-writeable memory, so it is a `const char *`, not a `char *`.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is expecting a pointer to a c-string (null terminated character array). Applying pointer arithmetic to it will allow access to the entire string. Note that `new[]` returns a pointer to the first element; it is (one way) how pointers are used.

Aside from the syntax errors, it makes no sense to pass a single character by reference to the class. It isn't interested in a single character, it is interested in where the beginning of the array is.

*It would be like asking somebody what their home address is, and they give you a rock from their lawn.*